# Условие вывода ошибки errorPlacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, валидация, формы, jquery-form

Всем привет

Для валидации формы использую jquery-validate

В форме есть дефолтный label с описанием поля и label для ошибки, задача такая, чтобы при получении ошибки на валидации дефолтный label скрывался, а label для ошибки наоборот появлялся и в него записывался текст ошибки. При введении в поле корректных данных ситуация обратная: label с ошибкой скрывается, дефолтный label появляется, пытаюсь решить через привязку к классу:

```
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var label = element.siblings('.site-label-form'),
            errorLabel = element.siblings('.site-label-form-error');

        if (element.hasClass('error')) {
            label.hide();
            errorLabel.text(error.text()).parent().addClass('focused');

        } else {
            label.show();
            errorLabel.hide();
        }

    }
});
```

Но почему то else не выполняется, буду рад помощи, вот полный код https://codepen.io/Ilinykh/pen/bPWGrW

Comment: Потому что, если поле валидное, то `errorPlacement` для него не вызывается.